# Elixir CRC will not compile on MAC OS

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-nif

My elixir project indirectly uses crc which has NIFs. They won't compile. It look like the linked does not see the libraries.

```
rtp_to_hls ●  rm -rf deps/ _build/ && mix deps.get && mix compile

==> crc
 C      checksum_xor.c
 C      crc_8.c
 C      crc_algorithm.c
 C      crc_model.c
 C      crc_nif.c
 C      crc_resource.c
 C      xnif_slice.c
 LD     crc_nif.so
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_enif_alloc", referenced from:
      _crc_model_load in crc_model.o
      _kh_resize_crc_stubs in crc_model.o
      _kh_resize_crc_models in crc_model.o
      _crc_nif_debug_table_1 in crc_nif.o
  "_enif_alloc_resource", referenced from:
      _crc_resource_create in crc_resource.o
      _crc_resource_clone in crc_resource.o
      _xnif_slice_create in xnif_slice.o
      _xnif_slice_create_x in xnif_slice.o
  "_enif_consume_timeslice", referenced from:
      _xnif_slice_trap in xnif_slice.o
  "_enif_free", referenced from:
      _crc_model_load in crc_model.o
      _crc_model_unload in crc_model.o
      _kh_resize_crc_stubs in crc_model.o
      _kh_resize_crc_models in crc_model.o
      _crc_nif_debug_table_1 in crc_nif.o
  "_enif_get_map_size", referenced from:
      _crc_init in crc_nif.o
      _crc_init_map_extend in crc_nif.o
  "_enif_get_map_value", referenced from:
      _crc_init in crc_nif.o
      _crc_init_map_extend in crc_nif.o
  "_enif_get_resource", referenced from:
      _crc_resource_get in crc_resource.o
      _xnif_slice_trap in xnif_slice.o
  "_enif_get_tuple", referenced from:
      _crc_init_tuple in crc_nif.o
  "_enif_get_uint", referenced from:
      _crc_nif_checksum_xor_1_work in checksum_xor.o
      _crc_nif_checksum_xor_1_done in checksum_xor.o
      _crc_nif_crc_8_2 in crc_8.o
      _crc_nif_crc_8_init_1 in crc_8.o
      _crc_nif_crc_8_update_2 in crc_8.o
      _crc_nif_crc_8_final_1 in crc_8.o
      _crc_nif_crc_8_2_work in crc_8.o
      ...
  "_enif_get_ulong", referenced from:
      _crc_init_tuple in crc_nif.o
  "_enif_inspect_binary", referenced from:
      _crc_nif_checksum_xor_1 in checksum_xor.o
      _crc_nif_checksum_xor_1_work in checksum_xor.o
      _crc_nif_crc_8_2 in crc_8.o
      _crc_nif_crc_8_update_2 in crc_8.o
      _crc_nif_crc_8_2_work in crc_8.o
      _crc_nif_crc_8_update_2_work in crc_8.o
  "_enif_inspect_iolist_as_binary", referenced from:
      _crc_nif_crc_fast_2 in crc_nif.o
      _crc_nif_crc_fast_update_2 in crc_nif.o
      _crc_nif_crc_slow_2 in crc_nif.o
      _crc_nif_crc_slow_update_2 in crc_nif.o
      _crc_nif_crc_fast_2_work in crc_nif.o
      _crc_nif_crc_fast_update_2_work in crc_nif.o
      _crc_nif_crc_slow_2_work in crc_nif.o
      ...
  "_enif_is_atom", referenced from:
      _crc_init in crc_nif.o
  "_enif_is_map", referenced from:
      _crc_init in crc_nif.o
  "_enif_is_ref", referenced from:
      _crc_init in crc_nif.o
  "_enif_is_tuple", referenced from:
      _crc_init in crc_nif.o
  "_enif_keep_resource", referenced from:
      _crc_resource_create in crc_resource.o
      _crc_resource_clone in crc_resource.o
  "_enif_make_atom", referenced from:
      _crc_model_load in crc_model.o
      _crc_model_list in crc_model.o
      _crc_nif_make_atoms in crc_nif.o
  "_enif_make_badarg", referenced from:
      _crc_nif_checksum_xor_1 in checksum_xor.o
      _crc_nif_checksum_xor_1_done in checksum_xor.o
      _crc_nif_crc_8_2 in crc_8.o
      _crc_nif_crc_8_init_1 in crc_8.o
      _crc_nif_crc_8_update_2 in crc_8.o
      _crc_nif_crc_8_final_1 in crc_8.o
      _crc_nif_crc_8_2_done in crc_8.o
      ...
  "_enif_make_list_from_array", referenced from:
      _crc_nif_debug_table_1 in crc_nif.o
  "_enif_make_map_put", referenced from:
      _crc_model_list in crc_model.o
      _crc_nif_crc_info_1 in crc_nif.o
  "_enif_make_new_binary", referenced from:
      _crc_model_list in crc_model.o
      _crc_nif_crc_info_1 in crc_nif.o
  "_enif_make_new_map", referenced from:
      _crc_model_list in crc_model.o
      _crc_nif_crc_info_1 in crc_nif.o
  "_enif_make_resource", referenced from:
      _crc_nif_crc_fast_2 in crc_nif.o
      _crc_nif_crc_fast_init_1 in crc_nif.o
      _crc_nif_crc_fast_update_2 in crc_nif.o
      _crc_nif_crc_slow_2 in crc_nif.o
      _crc_nif_crc_slow_init_1 in crc_nif.o
      _crc_nif_crc_slow_update_2 in crc_nif.o
      _xnif_slice_schedule in xnif_slice.o
      ...
  "_enif_make_tuple", referenced from:
      _crc_nif_debug_table_1 in crc_nif.o
      _crc_init in crc_nif.o
      _crc_init_map_extend in crc_nif.o
  "_enif_make_uint", referenced from:
      _crc_nif_checksum_xor_1 in checksum_xor.o
      _crc_nif_checksum_xor_1_work in checksum_xor.o
      _crc_nif_checksum_xor_1_done in checksum_xor.o
      _crc_nif_crc_8_2 in crc_8.o
      _crc_nif_crc_8_init_1 in crc_8.o
      _crc_nif_crc_8_update_2 in crc_8.o
      _crc_nif_crc_8_final_1 in crc_8.o
      ...
  "_enif_make_ulong", referenced from:
      _crc_nif_debug_table_1 in crc_nif.o
      _crc_nif_crc_fast_2 in crc_nif.o
      _crc_nif_crc_fast_final_1 in crc_nif.o
      _crc_nif_crc_slow_2 in crc_nif.o
      _crc_nif_crc_slow_final_1 in crc_nif.o
      _crc_nif_crc_info_1 in crc_nif.o
      _crc_nif_crc_residue_1 in crc_nif.o
      ...
  "_enif_monotonic_time", referenced from:
      _xnif_slice_trap in xnif_slice.o
  "_enif_open_resource_type", referenced from:
      _crc_resource_load in crc_resource.o
      _crc_resource_upgrade in crc_resource.o
      _xnif_slice_load in xnif_slice.o
      _xnif_slice_upgrade in xnif_slice.o
  "_enif_realloc", referenced from:
      _kh_resize_crc_stubs in crc_model.o
      _kh_resize_crc_models in crc_model.o
  "_enif_release_resource", referenced from:
      _crc_nif_crc_fast_2 in crc_nif.o
      _crc_nif_crc_fast_init_1 in crc_nif.o
      _crc_nif_crc_fast_update_2 in crc_nif.o
      _crc_nif_crc_slow_2 in crc_nif.o
      _crc_nif_crc_slow_init_1 in crc_nif.o
      _crc_nif_crc_slow_update_2 in crc_nif.o
      _crc_nif_crc_residue_1 in crc_nif.o
      ...
  "_enif_schedule_nif", referenced from:
      _xnif_slice_schedule in xnif_slice.o
      _xnif_slice_trap in xnif_slice.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [/Users/hajtojakub/Projects/membrane-demo/rtp_to_hls/_build/dev/lib/crc/priv/crc_nif.so] Error 1
could not compile dependency :crc, "mix compile" failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile crc", update it with "mix deps.update crc" or clean it with "mix deps.clean crc"
==> membrane_demo_rtp_to_hls
** (Mix) Could not compile with "make" (exit status: 2).
You need to have gcc and make installed. Try running the
commands "gcc --version" and / or "make --version". If these programs
are not installed, you will be prompted to install them.
```

I proceeded to check the env:

```
  rtp_to_hls ●  gcc --version                                     
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin



rtp_to_hls ●  make --version                                     
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

This is most likely configuration issue. I will post minimal reproducible project though

Comment: What library are you using for CRC? I'm guessing this: https://github.com/TattdCodeMonkey/crc
Are you using the latest version? If you clone the repo and run `mix do deps.get, compile` does it work?

Comment: Nope. I've done clean, mix deps.clean multiple times. As you seen in first post I've used `rm -rf deps/ _build/ && mix deps.get && mix compile`. So the output was with fresh deps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) development libraries, where this `_enif_***` family of functions is declared.

On Debian Linux:

- through [*Erlang Solutions*](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html) — preferrable
- using distro repo: `sudo apt install erlang-dev`

---

For MacOS, *Erlang Solutions* provide the ancient OTP version 19.3 only, I have no idea whether `brew` provides the latest OTP. If it does, do `brew install erlang-r23-dev` or like. If it does not, you are probably in a position to compile [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) yourself.

**NB** please refer to the very valuable comment below to see how to teach MacOS there is `dev` version already installed.

Comment: I know that. But on the Mac OS you don't have to install them separately. At the end of the installation I get this message:

Comment: Access them with `erl -man`, or add this directory to MANPATH.

erlang@22 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.

If you need to have erlang@22 first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/erlang@22/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find erlang@22 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/erlang@22/lib"

Comment: And I have added both of those exports to ~/.zshrc

Comment: Ouch. MacOS was never friendly to developers. I would leave this answer here for the sake of keeping the correct answer for Linux and your comment for MacOS. Also, `.zshrc` is too specific, it should be _“your shell resource file’_.